# Modify URL in asp.net zero

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, swagger, aspnetboilerplate

I have different tenants name and a login page whose path is `localhost:4200/account/login` but before that i have `localhost:4200/account/workspace` page where i will enter my tenantName in a textbox and the particular tenantId will be in the cookies. Now i want my next login page url to be like this 
`localhost:4200/tenantName/account/login` and even after login i want the tenantName exactly there throughout the whole session. I am new to this and completely stuck here for 2 days. How can i modify my url here? This is problem is almost similar to this problem here.

[https://forums.asp.net/t/2127416.aspx? How+to+modify+login+url+when+using+asp+net+identity](https://forums.asp.net/t/2127416.aspx?%20How%20to%20modify%20login%20url%20when%20using%20asp%20net%20identity)

The difference is that i have to make changes in my front-end and not in the backend and its asp.net zero not asp.net core. Here is the code for my root-routing module file.

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

 const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/app/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: 'account/account.module#AccountModule', //Lazy load account module
    data: { preload: true }
},
{
    path: 'app',
    loadChildren: 'app/app.module#AppModule', //Lazy load account module
    data: { preload: true }
}

];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule],
providers: [] 
})
export class RootRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Is the question about how to navigate from the route: /account/workspace to /tenantName/account/login after the textbox is filled in? Or do you want some type of automatic redirection?

Comment: sounds like your kind of making it hard for yourself.  is there about the the existing login page (where the user enters their Tenant name, username and password) that does not provide what you're asking here?

Comment: Actually there is a workspace page where the user provide the tenant name and then according to the tenant name it takes it on a login page where the user will have to write the username and password for that particular tenant. So for the workspace page i don't want to do anything on that but i want that when it go move to login page the tenant should be showing in the address bar like localhost:4200/tenantName/account/login. and no there i am not asking about navigation i am asking about configuring my routes by putting in tenantName property.

Comment: maybe you could add a param to the Account/Login with the tenant name - then use that as they login

Comment: if only it was that easy and right way to do this, i would have already done that